# Rails, RESTful routing, and pluralization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am struggling with the pluralization of the RESTful route generation in Rails 2.3.2.

Specifically, I have a resource called `sitestatus`. This resource really is uncountable (deer is deer, not deers). When I specify it as uncountable in an intializer, I get some helpers, but the `sitestatuses_path` is unavailable (which would make sense).

So, in a gesture to conformity, I have allowed `sitestatus` to be countable. So now, Rails pluralizes `sitestatus` to `sitestatuses` (not too horrible), but it insists on *also* singularizing it to `sitestatu` (missing the 's', hilarious and horrible at the same time).

So, I whipped out my bigger hammer and added this code to the intializer:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural "sitestatus", "sitestatuses"
  inflect.singular "sitestatus", "sitestatus"
end
```

(Note: I tried using `irregular` and it didn't work right)

Doing this gives me the expected results in the console when I `"sitestatus".pluralize`, but when I attempt to make a call to `sitestatuses_path` in my view I get

```
undefined local variable or method 'sitestatuses_path'
```

When I load up ActionController::UrlHelper in the console and call `sitestatus_path(123)` I get `sitestatus/123` as I would expect. However, when I call `sitestatuses_path` I get

```
undefined method 'sitestatuses_path' for #<Object...
```

This name is the name of the model and the controller and it really is the only logical name for both as it lines up with the business name for the object perfectly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does "sitestatuses" show up in the list of routes if you run rake routes?

Comment: No. The get route exists as sitestatus_index, but the post route is actually blank.

Comment: Just a note, REST has nothing to do with URI naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, as it turns out I didn't need to use the inflector. Rails was already doing the right thing with respect to the word `sitestatus`.

There were a couple problems and a couple solutions that I needed to employ.

Problem 1: I was using `map.resources :sitestatus`, not `map.resources :sitestatuses`. The "s" at the end of the word was making Rails think that it was already pluralized as it should be. Thus the funny `sitestatu_path` helpers.

Solution: Pluralize :sitestatus to :sitestatuses.

This created two problems:

Problem A: Rails now assumed that the controller was named "Sitestatuses" which it is not.
Solution A: Use the `:controller` hash_hey provided by the Rails router to rename the controller.

Problem B: Rails assumed that the url path that I wanted generated should be `/sitestatuses`, which it should not be.
Solution B: Use the `:as` hash_key to rename the url generated.

Now, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the named route method names for your routes and the urls for accesing them by invoking `rake routes`.